# git rebase -i for specific commits?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a branch with a few commits I'd like to interactively rebase.  However, after pulling and merging there are now other commits interleaved with mine so I can't just do something like `git rebase -i HEAD~3`

Is it possible to do an interactive rebase while choosing individual commits?  Something like `git rebase -i 23duirs 3eujsfe ...`

Another possibility-- If I simply run `git rebase -i` I believe it's possible to cut and paste my commit lines to be consecutive, and squash from there, is that correct?  Is there a best practice for doing so, to minimize the chance of conflicts with the unrelated commits in there?

Comment: In the future, don't merge in this scenario. You can use `git pull --rebase <remote> <branch>` if you have local changes on <branch>. This way you won't get the merge commit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given this

```
pick <unrelated a>
pick A
pick <unrelated b>
pick B
pick <unrelated c>
```

you can definitely do

```
pick <unrelated a>
pick <unrelated b>
pick <unrelated c>
pick A
squash B
```

Provided that your commit are **really** unrelated to the other changes, this will work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Rebasing after a merge is a pain in git.

I generally try to avoid this issue, by not merging others' work, but instead I fetch and rebase

```
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
```

(you can also use `git pull --rebase upstream master`, but this has a drawback of not updating your `remotes/upstream/master` tracking branch, which `git fetch` does; hence I prefer `fetch && rebase` instead of `pull --rebase`).

That way, my commits are always on top of everything in master, until my development is ready, then I open a pull request with a clean history without merges
I.e. at any point in time, last n commits in the branch that I am working on, are my commits, and I can easily reword, squash them etc.

The easiest way to amend some old commits is `git rebase -i`, and the param you pass to `git rebase -i` is a single commit-ish; **all the commits newer** than the provided commit will be displayed in the interactive rebase screen. I don't know of any way for this screen to just display *some* commits newer than the param.

The alternative to change old commits is `git filter-branch`, but it's rather much more complicated to use.

Comment: As of git 1.8.4, the `fetch` that `git pull` uses *does* update the remote tracking branches.  Separating out the fetch step can still be useful though since you can then see what changed upstream before you start a rebase.

Answer (score 0):

Little hacky solution.

Create a new local branch(LOCAL_B) from the origin. cherry-pick your commits from LOCAL_A to LOCAL_B and squash them using `git rebase -i HEAD~3`.

Now, take a backup of LOCAL_A for safety.

Delete LOCAL_A. Create new local branch LOCAL_A from the remote. Cherry-pick the squashed commit from LOCAL_B to LOCAL_A.

you are done.